# Want to download aws sdk billing using python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

write a lambda to download aws billing service using python is any api of billing service to perform this.

I tried with the "ce" but it is not that i am accepting , so i want to download the file through billing service

if you have any idea about that, share the idea. Thankyou in advance